# Running ink effect in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, brush

I'd like to create the effect of ink running similar to how it's been used in the example below. But I'd like to do it in vector. Anybody got some great brushes that might work?

[image: splatter paint rain]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm sure you've found, there are lots of [free vector 'splatters'](http://all-free-download.com/free-vector/free-illustrator-vector-splatter-brushes.html) out there. But I imagine you're looking for something generative.

Not even the great Scriptographer folks ever [came up with an answer for it](http://scriptographer.org/forum/wish-list/dripping-brush/), at least not one I've figured out yet. I was hoping it would come around eventually but now that plug-in has been retired.

Maybe the Scriptographer guys' current project ([Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/)) will solve it for us!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of an obvious answer, but if you specifically want to recreate realistic ink splatters as per your example, why not get some black ink, paper and start experimenting, then scan, (auto)trace and recolour?

Comment: sounds like a good plan.